# JMeter jp@gc-WebDriver Sampler — Graphs Generator (Synthesis Report)

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have installed the Synthesis Report Plugin, Command Line Plugin and JPCG-Standard Set to JMeter.

I have tried to run the script in Command Line & JMeter GUI.

I'm getting the CSV files but only one graph output. I have checked the log and don't find any error. Can you please advise?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing [Response Times Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ResponseTimesOverTime/) plugin

You can open jmx file in GUI and add plugin using plugin manager

Comment: Thanks. I have installed the JPCG-Standard Set and have only one graph output instead of 2 or more output graphs

Answer (score 0):

Graphs Generator generates a chart per your plugin installed, my expectation is that you have only [Response Times Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ResponseTimesOverTime/) therefore you're getting only it.

Try installing `3 Basic Graphs` and `5 Additional Graphs` bundles using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager) and you should get them all generated.

[image]